# React Higher Order Component (HOC) in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I am trying to write a React HOC in typescript but I am not getting the definitions correct. I am not sure if what I am trying to accomplish is possible.

Here is my code

```
import * as React from 'react'

export default function Ajax<Props, State>(InnerComponent: typeof React.Component): React.ComponentClass<Props & State> {
  return class extends InnerComponent<Props & State,any> {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
        request: 'initial'
      }
    }
    changeRequest(newRequest) {
      this.setState({request: 'loading'})
    }
    render() {
      return <InnerComponent 
        {...this.props } 
        {...this.state}
        changeRequest={this.changeRequest} 
      />
    }
  }
}
```

If i am just passing the props and state to the child it works. But how can I write the definitions to be able to pass additional props to the wrapped component? In this case the changeRequest prop.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know where is a problem. The wrapped component needs to know all properties, you shouldn't extend its properties definition in HOC.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work. But I am not sure this is the correct way. But now the compiler is not complaining and the code works. 
For the compiler stop complaining I had to add the props as javascript Objects.

Here is my working code:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export default function Ajax<Props, State> (InnerComponent: typeof React.Component): React.ComponentClass<Props & State> {
  return class extends InnerComponent<Props & State, any> {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
        request: 'initial'
      }
      this.changeRequest = this.changeRequest.bind(this)
    }
    changeRequest(newRequest) {
      this.setState({request: 'loading'})
    }
    render() {
      return <InnerComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} {...{onCLick: this.changeRequest}}/>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to bind the HOC's context to the changeRequest function.

```
constructor() {
  ...
  this.changeRequest = this.changeRequest.bind(this)
}
```

And make sure you're handling the prop in `InnerComponent`. For example.

`<InnerComponent onClick={this.props.changeRequest}>`

Comment: Hi Paul,
Thanks for the response.
It is not about binding the context. You need to bind to make the click work. But my issue is with the typings.